# Is multiplication by zero in an equation allowed?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

If we have equal quantities, we cannot divide with zero. But, we can multiply both sides with zero. But, my friend said, even multiplication with zero also wrong it seems. Unfortunately, he is not explaining the why wrong, if multiplication with zero on both sides?

Ex: $7 = 7$
If we multiply with zero on both sides, $0\times7 = 0\times7 \Rightarrow 0 = 0.$
But, multiplication with zero on both sides also illegal it seems. Why? 
Otherwise, in what cases, the multiplication with zero on both sides are not applicable. Please explain?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the inequality $a \neq b$. What happens when we multiply both sides by zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiplication of both sides of an equation by zero will always result in another true statement, it just won't be very useful. Multiplication by zero destroys information. The reason you can't divide both sides by zero is that division by zero just isn't defined, and there are plenty of threads here explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

Division by zero is undefined whereas multiplication by zero is defined. That's why multiplication by zero is "*legal*" whereas division by zero is "*illegal*".

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong: multiplication by zero is perfectly legal.

You are (always) allowed to multiply both sides of an equality by zero, or more generally, by any other number.